# visual layout of bidirectional text can depend on the base of direction view bidi text base Direction

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

After updating android studio to Flamingo, I can see "visual layout of bidirectional text can depend on the base of direction view bidi text base Direction" as in below picture:

[image]

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the direction for texts is content-based, which means that text direction is defined by the text with which the string begins. you can hide it.

See [developers bidi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/Bidi)